# How is `getattr` related to `object.__getattribute__` and to `object.__getattr__`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, built-in, magic-methods

From https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr

> ```
> getattr(object, name[, default])
> ```
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of `object`. name must be a
>   string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
>   the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x,
>   'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. If the named attribute does
>   not exist, `default` is returned if provided, otherwise
>   `AttributeError` is raised.

How is `getattr` related to `object.__getattribute__` and to `object.__getattr__`?

Does `getattr` call `object.__getattribute__` or `object.__getattr__`? I would guess the former?

Comment: All these `__getattr__` questions are mindnumbing...

Answer (score 9):

## Summary Answer

In general, a dotted lookup invokes __getattribute__.

If the code in [__getattribute__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) doesn't find the attribute, it looks to see if [__getattr__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) is defined.  If so, it is called.  Otherwise, *AttributeError* is raised.

The [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function is just an alternative way to call the above methods.  For example `getattr(a, 'x')` is equivalent to `a.x`.

The *getattr()* function is mainly useful when you don't know the name of an attribute in advance (i.e. when it is stored in a variable).  For example, `k = 'x'; getattr(a, k)` is equivalent to `a.x`.

## Analogy and high level point-of-view

The best way to think of it is that __getattribute__ is the first called primary method and __getattr__ is the fallback which is called when attributes are missing.  In this way, it is very much like the relationship between [__getitem__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and [__missing__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__) for square bracket lookups in dictionaries.

## Demonstration code

Here is a worked-out example:

```
>>> class A(object):
    x = 10
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        print(f'Looking up {attr!r}')
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print(f'Invoked the fallback method for missing {attr!r}')
        return 42

>>> a = A()
>>> a.x
Looking up 'x'
10
>>> a.y
Looking up 'y'
Invoked the fallback method for missing 'y'
42

>>> # Equivalent calls with getattr()
>>> getattr(a, 'x')
Looking up 'x'
10
>>> getattr(a, 'y')
Looking up 'y'
Invoked the fallback method for missing 'y'
42
```

## Official Documentation

Here are the relevant parts of the docs:

> object.__getattr__(self, name) Called when an attribute lookup has
>   not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an
>   instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for self). name
>   is the attribute name. This method should return the (computed)
>   attribute value or raise an AttributeError exception.
>
> Note that if the attribute is found through the normal mechanism,
>   __getattr__() is not called. (This is an intentional asymmetry between __getattr__() and __setattr__().) This is done both for efficiency reasons and because otherwise __getattr__() would have no way to
>   access other attributes of the instance. Note that at least for
>   instance variables, you can fake total control by not inserting any
>   values in the instance attribute dictionary (but instead inserting
>   them in another object). See the __getattribute__() method below for a
>   way to actually get total control over attribute access.
>
> object.__getattribute__(self, name) Called unconditionally to
>   implement attribute accesses for instances of the class. If the class
>   also defines __getattr__(), the latter will not be called unless
>   __getattribute__() either calls it explicitly or raises an *AttributeError*. This method should return the (computed) attribute
>   value or raise an *AttributeError* exception. In order to avoid infinite
>   recursion in this method, its implementation should always call the
>   base class method with the same name to access any attributes it
>   needs, for example, object.__getattribute__(self, name).

Comment: Is there a way to call a method in a similar way? Something like `getmethod(x, 'mean')` will be like `x.mean()`?

Comment: @Royi Yes, take a look at the operator module:   ``operator.methodcaller(x, 'mean')``.

Answer (score 3):

`getattr(foo, 'bar')`(which is basically `foo.bar`) calls `__getattribute__` and from there `__getattr__` can be called(if it exists) when:

1. `AttributeError` is raised by `__getattribute__`
2. `__getattribute__` calls it explicitly

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__):

> If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the latter will not be called
>   unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it explicitly or raises an
>   `AttributeError`.

Defining `__getattr__` can be useful if you don't want to throw attribute errors on random attribute access. [Mock library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) is great example of that.

```
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock
>>> m = Mock()
>>> m.foo.bar.spam
<Mock name='mock.foo.bar.spam' id='4367274280'>
```

If you don't want to define `__getattr__` all the time nor want to handle `AttributeError` all the time then you could either use the 3 argument form of `getattr()` to return default value if attribute wasn't found or use `hasattr` to check for its existence.

```
>> getattr([], 'foo')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-f1834c32d3ce> in <module>()
----> 1 getattr([], 'foo')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> getattr([], 'foo', 'default')
'default'
```

**Demo:**

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print('Inside A.__getattr__')
        return 'eggs'

print(A().foo)
```

**outputs:**

```
Inside A.__getattr__
eggs
```

---

Note that the data model documentation points it out as `object.__getattr__`, but that doesn't mean they exists on builtin `object` type. Instead they can exist on any object in general. And object in this case is a type as dunder methods are looked up on an object's type.

Comment: Thanks. Is `__getattr__` a method of `object`?  So everything has `__getattr__` by default, because everything inherits `object`?

Comment: @Tim `object.__getattr__` doesn't exist(probably because there's no point in having `__geattr__` there, `AttributeError` is all we need) , but a user defined class can have a custom defined `__getattr__` to handle attribute errors. `__getattr__` exists in old-style classes in Python 2.

Comment: `object.__getattr__`   exists https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__

Comment: @Tim It can exist on an object, it doesn't mean the builtin `object` type.

Comment: @Tim You can see this for yourself by doing: `hasattr(object, '__getattr__')`.

Comment: Why does the link list the methods qualified by `object.`, if `object` doesn't have the methods?

Comment: @Tim It's somewhat confusing, but read them as these methods can or already exist on an object instead of these methods exist on builtin `object` type.

Comment: This answer can be improved by taking out the unnecessary use of metaclasses which is a distractor issue.  Also, the OP specifically asked about *object.\__getattribute__()* rather than *type.\__getattribute__*.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger I added that based on OP's previous set of question and also to clarify the fact that it's doesn't necessarily have to be `object`, it could any type. They for one thought that `object.__getattr__` exists on `object` type because documentation mentions it, but that's not true. Documentation's use of `object` is not clear there. IMO it may be distracting for other users but not OP as far as I can tell.

Comment: That okay.  It is just a difference of opinion on how best to explain things.  For me, it seems like a person was asking how a car works (getattr, getattribute), and got an explanation that included cars (getattr), nuclear powerplants (metaclasses), and trains (mock objects).  ISTM that style can do more harm than good.